# Suppress VIEW on a specific URL

Tags: views

There are two URL's on which I want to suppress a VIEW , Below are the urls's :

http://mysite.com/drupal/?q=searchpanel&body_value=

http://mysite.com/drupal/?q=searchpanel

How can I stop a view to appear on above link .

Thanks for any help in this!

Answer (score 0):

Create the view and render it as a block, then go to block settings, set the view to show on every page except:

> drupal/?q=searchpanel&body_value=
>
> drupal/?q=searchpanel

Edit: Add the created view block to the content area where you want it to display e.g footer, content etc. it will show on every page except the pages above

Comment: Actually my VIEW is created as "content Pane " and is placed in a Panel page . Is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: You can add a block to the view, it will still contain data as the original view, then you can go to the block page, locate the created block and override the pages it will display as per my answer above